# how to change the style of react components on click?

Tags: reactjs

Iam trying to implement conway's game of life using react.js.To do this,i have used board consisting of cells,which toggle between colors black and pink,when user clicks,state variable BoardState is used to keep track of changes.Though all cells respond to click event calling function:handleClick to change state and background-color,while state state changes,background color remains same except that of last cell,which changes color of cells

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/renx777/pen/oGmEEg?editors=0010)!

```
const Cell = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {

      row: 3,
      col: 3
    };
  },
  //handles click event,changes the state of the board
  handleClick(evt) {
    var id = evt.target.id.split(" ");
    var i = parseInt(id[0]);
    var j = parseInt(id[1]);

    var newBoard = this.state.BoardState;

    if (newBoard[i][j] == 0) {
      newBoard[i][j] = 1;
    } else {
      newBoard[i][j] = 0;
    }

    this.setState({
      BoardState: newBoard
    });
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    var board = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.row; i++) {
      var dummy = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < this.state.col; j++) {
        dummy.push(0);
      }
      board.push(dummy);
    }

    this.setState({
      BoardState: board
    });
  },
  render() {
    var style = {
      height: "11px",
      width: "11px",

      display: "inline-block",
      border: "1px solid #222"
    };
    var Board = [];
    var bState = this.state.BoardState;
    console.log(bState);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.row; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < this.state.col; j++) {
        //change color of the cell depending upon the state of the cell
        if (bState[i][j] == 0) {
          style.background = "black";
        }
        if (bState[i][j] == 1) {
          style.background = "pink";
        }

        Board.push(
          <div onClick={this.handleClick} style={style} id={i + " " + j} />
        );
      }

      Board.push(<div id="hide">i</div>);
    }
    console.log(Board);

    return (
      <div>
        <div id="board">{Board}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Cell />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your style declaration inside the loop. You can't use same style Object for all the cells. 
Here's an updated pen
https://codepen.io/pavanmehta/pen/RLOzdV?editors=0010

```
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.row; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < this.state.col; j++) {
    var style = {
     height: "11px",
     width: "11px",
     display: "inline-block",
     border: "1px solid #222"
    };
```

**Working Demo** :

```js
const Cell = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      row: 3,
      col: 3
    };
  },
  //handles click event,changes the state of the board
  handleClick(evt) {
    var id = evt.target.id.split(" ");
    var i = parseInt(id[0]);
    var j = parseInt(id[1]);

    var newBoard = this.state.BoardState;

    if (newBoard[i][j] == 0) {
      newBoard[i][j] = 1;
    } else {
      newBoard[i][j] = 0;
    }

    this.setState({
      BoardState: newBoard
    });
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    var board = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.row; i++) {
      var dummy = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < this.state.col; j++) {
        dummy.push(0);
      }
      board.push(dummy);
    }

    this.setState({
      BoardState: board
    });
  },
  
  render() {
    var Board = [];
    var bState = this.state.BoardState;
    console.log(bState);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.row; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < this.state.col; j++) {
        var style = {
          height: "11px",
          width: "11px",
          display: "inline-block",
          border: "1px solid #222"
        };
        //change color of the cell depending upon the state of the cell
        if (bState[i][j] == 0) {
          style.background = "black";
        } else {
          style.background = "pink";
        }

        Board.push(
          <div onClick={this.handleClick} style={style} id={i + " " + j} />
        );
      }
      Board.push(<div id="hide">i</div>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div id="board">{Board}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Cell />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```